# Bug Firefox 33.0.2 Combobox

Tags: firefox, combobox

I have a bug on Firefox 33.0.2 (Mac and PC) this problem does not exist on IE and Chrome and Safari.
Here is the problem I have a joomla site with a combobox (3 elements in it) impossible to select with the mouse one of these elements only solution open it and selected with the keypad.

Thank you in advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with the delivery of 33.0.3

thank you